# Dynamics AX 2009 batch job SSRS reporting pdf

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, batch-processing, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Is it technically possible to save SSRS reports to pdf files(without images inside) through x++ batch job?
If possible, which classes can I use to do that in AX 2009 without SP1?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Tried this ? http://axwonders.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/save-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-report.html

Answer (score 0):

SSRS has a Subscription tool that you can used to save and or email reports to various formats.  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) provides information on this.

Comment: Please copy the relevant data into the answer instead of merely linking to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    salesQuotation = qr.get(tablenum(salesQuotationTable));
    filenamePDF = strfmt("%1%2",SalesQuotation.QuotationId,".pdf");

    permissionSetPDF =  new Set(Types::Class);
    permissionSetPDF.add(new FileIOPermission(filenamePDF,'w'));
    permissionSetPDF.add(new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop));
    CodeAccessPermission::assertMultiple(permissionSetPDF);

    report = new ReportRun(new Args(ReportStr(SalesQuotation)));
    report.query().interactive(false);
    report.report().interactive(false);
    report.args().caller(null);

    report.args().parm(SalesQuotation.QuotationId);

    report.printJobSettings().setTarget(PrintMedium::File);
    report.printJobSettings().format(PrintFormat::PDF);
    report.printJobSettings().warnIfFileExists(false);
    report.printJobSettings().fileName(strfmt("%1%2",path,filenamePDF));

    report.run();
    CodeAccessPermission::revert();
```